# Is Calling static in c# as in my example safe to do?

Tags: c#

I've have several simple helper methods that I've put in a utils.cs class. An example is one below.  I call this from an asp.net controller which means that there could be many calls happening on many threads around the same time.

I realize I do this because resharper suggests making the method in the class static but I'm worried maybe that's the wrong thing to do and maybe I should new up the Utils class every call.

Thoughts?

```
public class Utils
    {
        public static List<Speaker> FilterSpeakersByTenant(List<Speaker> inSpeakers, string tenantName)
        {
            return
                inSpeakers.
                    Where(speaker => speaker.Sessions.
                        Any(a => a.TenantName == tenantName)).
                    ToList();
        }
```

Comment: static should be fine. side question: can you key this data based on tenants instead of speakers? would greatly speed up the process as a whole.

Comment: this is a common pattern for extension methods, in fact `Where` and `Any` look just like your `FilterSpeakersByTenant`. Change the signature of your method to `public static IEnumerable<Speaker> FilterByTenant(this IEnumerable<Speaker> inSpeakers, string tenantName)` and you can use it like this: `mySpeakersList.FilterByTenant("theTenantName")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resharper suggests that you make it a static method because it does not access any instance members.  Since you *also* don't access any static data you are safe from multithreading issues as well.

So long as you don't add any static or non-static fields that the method will use, there's no downside to making it `static`.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not access global/shared state in your static method then it should be fine...

The only multithreading problem may arise when you access your parameters (e.g. the list) in concurrent threads.

If the class does not have any state (i.e. member variables or properties) it does not make a difference whether you instantiate the class or use a static method.

Answer (score 1):

It is fine. A non static class can inherit from an interface. You do not need seem to need that here. A non static class can be used to create multiple objects with multiple states. You also do not need that.

Answer (score 0):

The method is completely thread safe. It doesn't use any shared state, and it doesn't modify the parameters.

For better readability, consider changing your method to an extension method on `IEnumerable<Speaker>`:

```
public static IEnumerable<Speaker> ByTenant(this IEnumerable<Speaker> source, string tenantName)
    {
        return source
               .Where(speaker => speaker.Sessions.Any(a => a.TenantName == tenantName));
    }
```

Then you can use it as

```
var filteredSpeakers = speakers.ByTenant(tenantName).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Safe is such overrated concept, is not it? :).
The problem is, that it is not a thread safe method because the input data:

```
List<Speaker> inSpeakers
```

can be changed in same time as it is enumerated by LINQ Where operator, it would throw a exception because otherwise there would be race condition.

If you are certain, that the method gets only copy of original list, then OK, but I do not see such guarantee here. List are used to add/remove items and access them.

Other ways to handle thread safety is locking, which has performance side effect in case of high contention.

Little better would be array, number of items can not be change.

Very good idea would be ImmutableList.

And if you are actualy looking for way to share state in list between many threads, then some  concurrent collletction would be best case.